# ¿Como eliminar margen en mi AppBarLayout?

Tags: android

Buen dia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como podria eliminar las margenes o espacios?

De antemano gracias

Este es el layout del AppBarLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.com.mayorgafirm.saxtant.activity.LeftMenuActivity"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/NavigationViewTheme"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.CustomTheme"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Aqui el content_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:gravity="top">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_login"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Agrega el layout de tu barra. Usas un Toolbar verdad? =)

Comment: he visto la actualización podrías por favor agregar content_main.xml que es lo que carga dentro este layout.

Answer (score 0):

Para que quede sin los espacios, define las propiedades de tu toolbar con valor 0 :

```
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:contentInsetRight="0dp"

app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
```